# Can I leave Germany before my long term visa expires, came back after and take Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, london

I'm brazilian, living in Germany with a type D visa (for internship) that expires on 31.07.2018.
If I go to London(UK) and come back on 01.08.2018, can I stay here for 90 more days?
I entered in Germany on 30.01.2018. So 01.08 will be more than 180 days.

Comment: This has surely already been asked and answered, but I cannot find the duplicate.  The answer is that you can do this, because your time in Germany under the type D visa is explicitly excluded from the 90/180 calculation.

Comment: I couldn't find any case like mine too. Thanks for your answer!